# adb shell dumpsys diskstats show uninstalled packages

Tags: android, package, adb, uninstallation, dumpsys

Parsing `adb shell dumpsys diskstats` show some packages that does not seems to be installed.

For example, I find `find.out.hidden.objects.seek.puzzle.games.free`:

```
find.out.hidden.objects.seek.puzzle.games.free (216412160, 33533952)
```

(First number is app size and the second one is app data size, in bytes).

But it’s not available in package list:

```bash
$ adb shell pm list packages | grep find.out
```

(This return nothing).

And it’s not uninstallable or clearable:

```bash
$ adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 find.out.hidden.objects.seek.puzzle.games.free
Failure [not installed for 0]
$ adb shell pm clear --user 0 find.out.hidden.objects.seek.puzzle.games.free
Failed
```

(Same for `--user 1`).

So I’m not sure to understand what this package information and size come from.

Is this application installed somewhere? Can I uninstall it?

Comment: May be it is a pre-installed app by the phone manufacturer? For example if I disable youtube app I can still see it in `dumpsys diskstats` with a size of 229430784.